# How to declare a sparse Vector in Spark with Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, seq, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to create a sparse Vector (the [mllib.linalg.Vectors](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors$) class, not the default one) but I can't understand how to use Seq. I have a small test file with three numbers/line, which I convert to an rdd, split the text in doubles and then group the lines by their first column.

Test file

```
1 2 4
1 3 5    
1 4 8    
2 7 5    
2 8 4    
2 9 10
```

Code

```
val data = sc.textFile("/home/savvas/DWDM/test.txt")
val data2 = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble)))
val grouped = data2.groupBy( _(0) )
```

This results in `grouped` having these values

```
(2.0,CompactBuffer([2.0,7.0,5.0], [2.0,8.0,4.0], [2.0,9.0,10.0]))
(1.0,CompactBuffer([1.0,2.0,4.0], [1.0,3.0,5.0], [1.0,4.0,8.0]))
```

But I can't seem to figure out the next step. I need to take each line of `grouped` and create a vector for it, so that each line of the new RDD has a vector with the third value of the `CompactBuffer` in the index specified by the second value. In short, what I mean is that I want my data in the example like this.

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.0, 4.0, 10.0, 0]
[0, 4.0, 5.0, 8.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I know I need to use a sparse vector, and that there are three ways to construct it. I've tried using a Seq with a tuple2(index, value) , but I cannot understand how to create such a Seq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is something like below. First lets convert data to expected types:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val pairs: RDD[(Double, (Int, Double))] = data.map(_.split(" ") match {
  case Array(label, idx, value) => (label.toDouble, (idx.toInt, value.toDouble))
})
```

next find a maximum index (size of the vectors):

```
val nCols = pairs.map{case (_, (i, _)) => i}.max + 1
```

group and convert:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector

def makeVector(xs: Iterable[(Int, Double)]) = {
  val (indices, values) = xs.toArray.sortBy(_._1).unzip
  new SparseVector(nCols, indices.toArray, values.toArray)
}

val transformed: RDD[(Double, SparseVector)] = pairs
  .groupByKey
  .mapValues(makeVector)
```

Another way you can handle this, assuming that the first elements can be safely converted to and from integer, is to use `CoordinateMatrix`:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{CoordinateMatrix, MatrixEntry}

val entries: RDD[MatrixEntry] = data.map(_.split(" ") match {
  case Array(label, idx, value) => 
    MatrixEntry(label.toInt, idx.toInt, value.toDouble)
})

val transformed: RDD[(Double, SparseVector)] = new CoordinateMatrix(entries)
  .toIndexedRowMatrix
  .rows
  .map(row => (row.index.toDouble, row.vector))
```

Comment: It does the job but it seems a little to complicated and it gives me the impression that there's more simple code to do this. Anyway, I'm really new to scala and I get confused very easily!